# Collision Detection Not Reporting Correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I posted before about this project I'm working on (and your answers helped!) but I'm still a little fuzzy on why my collision detection isn't quite reporting correctly. It is returning true for every tile the play walks on, including when I move my player character onto a collidable tile. I just want to know if there's a problem with my collision detection algorithm or if there's a problem elsewhere.

```
def checkPlayerEnvCollision(self,player):
    rowCount = 0
    for row in self.cLayer:
        colCount = 0
        for col in row:
            print("col: " + str(col))
            #print(str(self.Level.tileLayer[row][col]) + ": " + str(c[row][col]))
            if col:
                grid_position = (colCount*32, rowCount*32)
                collide_x = False
                collide_y = False

                print(str(grid_position))
                # check x axis for collision
                if player.x + 32 > grid_position[0]:
                    collide_x = True
                elif player.x < grid_position[0] + 32:
                    collide_x = True

                print("Player x: " + str(player.x) + " Player y : " + str(player.y))


                # check y axis for collision
                if player.y < grid_position[1] + 32:
                    collide_y = True
                elif player.y + 32 > grid_position[1]:
                    collide_y = True

                print("collide_x: " + str(collide_x) + " " + "collide_y: "+ str(collide_y))

                # act on a collision on both axis
                if collide_x and collide_y:
                    print("COLLISION DETECTED")
                else:
                    print("NOCOLLISION___")
            colCount += 1
        rowCount += 1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Have you tried printing out colCount, rowCount, grid_position[0], grid_position[1], player.x and player.y to see which of the numbers is wrong or if they are all right?

Comment: Yes, I have it all printed out into the console. When the player's x and y are on a collidable square, according to the printouts, it should be registering as a collision. It's so frustrating!

Comment: Actually, the problem is that it IS printing true for a collision--every time.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that was the problem when you posted :)

Comment: I edited the print statements right before I posted, not realizing it would affect it. I apologize! I should have checked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think code like this:

```
            if player.x + 32 > grid_position[0]:
                collide_x = True
            elif player.x < grid_position[0] + 32:
                collide_x = True
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
            if grid_position[0] + 32 > player.x > grid_position[0]:
                collide_x = True
```

(yes, it is a feature of Python that you can chain comparison operators like that)

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I figured it must have been a problem with my logic somewhere.